# Tool to define screen relationships diagrams?

Tags: tools, flowcharts, diagramming

Is there any tools, other than Visio, to create diagrams defining UI flows (how the different screens of a program or app relate to each other?).

Something like the diagrams shown here:
http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/screen-planning.html

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to User Experience! Sorry, but questions requesting recommendations for books / software / apps / papers etc. would fall into the [shopping request](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) category and aren't really suitable to a Q&A website. The reason for this is that there is no one correct answer, and such recommended items would soon be updated and replaced with newer / better versions making the best answers redundant. Therefore you're better off visiting our Chat site for such discussions, they're not really suitable for this main site I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Omnigraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com) or [Axure](http://www.axure.com).

I find Omnigraffle to be faster to work with when it comes to flow charts but Axure to provide a better all-in-one solution (flow charts, wireframing, prototyping and user-testing.

Comment: Thanks TotemFlare,
I forgot Axure can do such things and is actually quite good at it.